# How to create multiple tables based on JSON values

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to create multiple tables based on values from an object.

```
[
    {
        itemFolder: "personal"
        itemLocation: "right infront of me"
        itemName: "macBook"
        itemNotes: "Space Gray"
    },
    {
        itemFolder: "professional"
        itemLocation: "behind me"
        itemName: "Dell"
        itemNotes: "Black"
    },
    {
        itemFolder: "student"
        itemLocation: "left of me"
        itemName: "HP"
        itemNotes: "silver"
    },
    {
        itemFolder: "worker"
        itemLocation: "right of me"
        itemName: "Lenovo"
        itemNotes: "black"
    },
    {
        itemFolder: "worker"
        itemLocation: "behind me"
        itemName: "HP"
        itemNotes: "silver"
    },
    // around 20 more items
]
```

I want to create several different tables, where the item location, name, and notes are displayed, and the tables are filtered/centered around what is inside of `itemFolder`. How would I do that?

For example:

```
Worker:

itemlocation:   itemName:

right of me     Lenovo

behind me       HP
```

and then for professional, student, and so on.

Comment: Build the actual JSON object and post it here. You should also look into [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). You will see that you can easily bind your JSON objects to DataTables which comes with a filter by default.

Comment: [There is no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) You just have an array of objects. No need to embellish that with acronyms.

Comment: Sounds like you want to group your objects by a property? There are a number of questions about that, depending on the end result you want. I'd suggest [How to group an array of objects by key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40774697/215552)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood exactly what you want

But since you want to display data in a table, I came up with this simple 5 step JS implementation of a table using your data, hope it helps

1. I encapsulated your data in a const, so that we have an array of items, each being an object

```
const data = [
  {
    itemFolder: "personal",
    itemLocation: "right infront of me",
    itemName: "macBook",
    itemNotes: "Space Gray",
  },
  {
    itemFolder: "professional",
    itemLocation: "behind me",
    itemName: "Dell",
    itemNotes: "Black",
  },
  {
    itemFolder: "student",
    itemLocation: "left of me",
    itemName: "HP",
    itemNotes: "silver",
  },
 // ...
];
```

2. Then I create some HTML elements needed for us to have a table

```
const table = document.createElement("table");
const thead = document.createElement("thead");
const tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

table.appendChild(thead);
table.appendChild(tbody);
```

3. Here we make our table header: We're simply iterating over one array's object keys, and appending a new th element to our previously created thead, for each property our objcet has.
   We should also set the textContent of the tr element with the property key name

```
for (let key of Object.keys(data[0])) {
  const th = document.createElement("th");
  th.textContent = key;
  thead.appendChild(th);
}
```

4. And finally we iterate over the data.
   For each piece of data we will create 4 td elements
   Each of them should receive a property value as it's textContent.
   At the bottom, we append our td elements to the tbody

```
data.forEach((item, i) => {
  const tr = document.createElement("tr");

  const td0 = document.createElement("td");
  const td1 = document.createElement("td");
  const td3 = document.createElement("td");
  const td2 = document.createElement("td");

  td0.textContent = item.itemFolder;
  td1.textContent = item.itemName;
  td2.textContent = item.itemLocation;
  td3.textContent = item.itemNotes;

  tr.appendChild(td0);
  tr.appendChild(td1);
  tr.appendChild(td2);
  tr.appendChild(td3);

  tbody.appendChild(tr);
});
```

5. Last step, append our whole creation to the DOM

```
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

The result is something like this:

[image]

the only styling I added was

```
td, th {
 border: 1px solid;
}
```

But you can definitely do a lot better in your CSS

Answer (score 0):

```
const table = (a) =>`<table>${a}</table>`;
const tr = (a) =>`<tr>${a}</tr>`;
const td = (a) =>`<td>${a}</td>`;

const tableFromArrayObjects = (data) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
  return table(
    tr(keys.map(td).join("")) +
      data
        .map((v) =>
          keys
            .map(td)
            .join("")
        )
        .map(tr)
        .join("")
  );
};
```